# Php - pdf parser

Tags: php, parsing, pdf

i try to find a pdf parser. I search in stackoverflow but there's no satisfactory answers. Some say that Zend is good to do that but i dont want to use it. Is there are good class to do that ?

Comment: Why don't you want to use Zend? Any particular reason, or just general dislike of all things Zend?

Comment: i think zend is suitable for big projects. I only want to read two pdf.

Comment: You don't need to use the entirety of Zend Framework just to read a PDF, select just the components you want/need.

Comment: pdflib could not do this.It only generates pdf files .

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how deep you need to go the pdf parsing but [here](https://github.com/Micka33/content-extractor/blob/master/parser.py) is something I have done very recently to extract pdf text into a json string. it will also extract the images, but if you don't want them you can still comment these two lines in the run function in pdfreader/main.py

```
extract_images(pdf_file)
dict_book = get_images_update_dict(dict_book, image_folder)
```

Yes it's in python not in php, but you can get back the result in json the following way:

```
exec("./parser.py pdfreader/book.pdf './images/' 2>&1", $output);
$data = json_decode($output)
var_dump($data);
```